# RegEx to replace password in Linux shell script?

Tags: regex, linux, shell

I have a string that contains parameters like password etc. Anything after `-P` is a password followed by some other parameters like -H host etc. Parameters may be in any order

Ex1: `sh script.ksh -U test_user -P somepwd -H somehost`

Ex2: `sh script.ksh -U test_user -H somehost -P somepwd`

Now, I want to replace password with the word removed

Result1: `sh script.ksh -U test_user -P REMOVED -H somehost`

Result2: `sh script.ksh -U test_user -H somehost -P REMOVED`

How, is the possible. I tried the following.

```
sed -i -E "s/(.*[-]P)(\b.*\b)(.*)/\1\something\3/" test_pwd_replace.txt
```

But, it is not working. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `sed`:

```
sed -i -E 's/-P[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]+/-P REMOVED/' test_pwd_replace.txt
```

`[[:blank:]]` is equivalent of `[ \t]` that matches a whitespace or a tab character.